# How to insert an unicode in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function, unicode

I'm using a font with specified unicode. Instead of displaying the symbol it will only show the numbers or a broken image..

```
.attr('title', '&#xe08f;');
```

Does anybody knows how to write this correctly? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify the unicode codepoint directly

```
.attr('title', '\uE08F')
```

Answer (score 1):

The string literal `'&#xe08f;'` denotes a string of seven characters (&, #, etc.) in JavaScript. If your code happens to be embedded in an HTML document, then it may or may not (depending on browser mode) be processed so that the characters `&#xe08f;` are recognized as a character reference denoting U+E08F before passing the data to the JavaScript interpreter.

As Andbdrew’s answer implicitly says, the JavaScript way to denote a character, inside a string literal, by its Unicode number is to use the `\u` prefix, e.g. `\ue08f`.

Independently of this, the code point U+E08F is a Private Use code point, and as per the Unicode Standard, “These characters are designated for private use and do not have defined,
interpretable semantics except by private agreement.” So if these code points are used to extend character repertoire, it is more or less *guaranteed* that there will be no interoperability. In this case, when they work, they work only if a very specific font, with assignments for the code points, is used.

Answer (score 0):

The title attribute doesn't interpret HTML.

You may simply do this :

```
 ... attr('title', '');
```

[demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Gja9z/)

Of course you need to properly encode your document. UTF-8 is the most reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use specific font in title attribute. But you can use handmade tooltip instead of title attribute which you can fill with any text you want.

Comment: I think you should take a look at this link ;) http://kudakurage.com/ligature_symbols/

Comment: Sure I was there! But where's title-attribute there I can see?

Comment: Read the discription below, there are two ways to implement those symbols.